# runtime.xml file loaction in coldfusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I've ColdFusion 2016 developer edition installed on my Windows 10 and cannot find the runtime.xml file there. Where should it be? I need to change the following setting in the file to resolve **this error**: `POST parameters exceeds the maximum limit`. The error is similar to the [one shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957698/1232087).

```
<var name='postParametersLimit'><number>100.0</number></var>
```

**Note**: If someone has any other suggestion to resolve the error I'm getting, please let me know.

Comment: There is an option in the CF admin to change this value. Why not change it there?

Comment: @haxtbh Good suggestion - thank you. I think, this option was introduced in CF10 and  it is still there in ColdFusion2016. To get to it in admin: Server Settings / `Settings / Request Size Limits / Maximum number of POST request parameters`

Comment: @haxtbh That's the ideal and recommended way!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by going through [this article](http://blog.cartweaver.com/coldfusion-post-size-limit-causes-400-or-500-error-on-large-forms/). The file name, in my case, is `neo-runtime.xml` and it's located on `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\lib\neo-runtime.xml`. Thank you those who may have tried to help.