# How to fix 'POST request Exceeded' error while we passed the number of parameters to the server using API call (POST request) in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, coldfusion-2018

In my Application, I have the 300 user permissions for user role 'admin'. As a super admin, added a new admin users means, need to enable the user permissions for this admin user. If I choose below 100 and sent it to the backend via API call POST method, I can able to get the success response.

But, If I'm selecting more than 100 means, I couldn't able to get the success response. It's throwing error message like 'POST request Exceeded'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the amount of fields that can be posted in a form with IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882788/how-to-change-the-amount-of-fields-that-can-be-posted-in-a-form-with-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure, ColdFusion has some settings for this. So, I just read ColdFusion server settings docs and found the solution.

### For Fixing this issue follow the below steps,

1. Logged in to CFAdmin
2. Go to 'settings' under the 'server settings' section.
3. In the bottom of the page, CF has 'Maximum number of POST request parameters' as 100. We need to change that 100 into 300.
4. Also, need to set the 'Maximum size of post data'. by default, 20 MB. So, Need to change this also.
5. After changing the default values, We need to restart the CF server.

[image]